# Suppose the number n = 90k is the smallest integer that has exactly ninety divisors (all positive integers) which includes 1 and n. Find k

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose the number n = 90k is the smallest integer that has exactly ninety divisors (all
positive integers) which includes 1 and n. Find k.

I know this question has been answered, but I am wondering if there is an elementary way to answer this using modular arithmetic and/or Euler's totient function?

Comment: To avoid wasting people's time, it is polite to give a link to where the question was answered before. Perhaps you were thinking of this: [Smallest integer that is divisible by 90 and has exactly 90 distinct positive divisors](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2764385/139123).

Answer (score 3):

We have, $N=90k=2\cdot3^2\cdot5\cdot(k)$

Number of divisors of a number is product of the $(\text{powers}+1)$ of each of the it's prime factors.
Since we want exactly $90$ divisors, so the product would look like:
$$\begin {align} 90 &=2\cdot3^2\cdot5 \\ &= 2\cdot3\cdot3\cdot5 \tag A \\ &= 6\cdot3\cdot5 \tag B \\ &= 2\cdot9\cdot5 \tag C \\ &= 2\cdot3\cdot15 \tag D\end{align}$$

Note: $(A),(B),(C),(D)$ limit our prime factors to 3 or 4 only.

Case (A):
$N=ab^2c^2d^4$
Here, we need to assign lowest prime number to the factor with highest power.
Thus, $a=7,b=5,c=3,d=2$
Thus, $N=25200$

Case (B):
$N=a^5b^2c^4$
Here, we need to assign lowest prime number to the factor with highest power.
Thus, $a=2,b=5,c=3$
Thus, $N=64800$

Case (C):
$N=ab^8c^4$
Here, we need to assign lowest prime number to the factor with highest power.
Thus, $a=5,b=2,c=3$
Thus, $N=103680$

Case (D):
$N=ab^2c^{14}$
Here, we need to assign lowest prime number to the factor with highest power.
Thus, $a=5,b=3,c=2$
Thus, $N=737280$

So, the smallest number satisfying the given conditions is $25200$.

$\therefore 90k=25200$
$$\Rightarrow \boxed {k=280}$$

Comment: Small comment (You've done all the real work): OP asks to find $k$, which is just $\frac{25200}{90}=280$

Comment: @KeithBackman LOL! It's like showing all the working and then not writing the answer (In exams here, teachers sadly cut students' half marks for this!) Editing...